# How can I redirect database requests in my postgres server

Tags: postgresql, psql, maintenance

So I have a list of(lot many) scrapers which push lot many data into one of my database location. Unfortunately I have a requirement that my database location  have to be changed for some performance issues. Rather than changing my so many scripts config can I have some mechanism implemented in my db server so that database requests coming from certain IP(machines) I would redirect  them to other database/server?

Comment: pgBouncer can do that: https://pgbouncer.github.io/

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name! can you give some good documentation links?

Comment: https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @horse_with_no_name already comment: you can use pgbouncer to do that.

Basically you need to create a pool configuration, and during your maintenance you ajust the pool config to a new server or database.

Take a look at the session `[databases]` on `/etc/pgbouncer.ini` file:

```
[databases]
; no connection info enforces unix socket
foodb =
; bardb config
bardb = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=bardb
```

So, if you want to redirect the connections for the database `bardb` for another database, what you need to do is edit the `dbname` and reload de pgbouncer service. E.G.:

```
; bardb config
bardb = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=maintenancedb
```

Please, take a look at the documentation<sup>[1]</sup> for more details.

You can do the same with the pgpool<sup>[2]</sup>.

Hope it helps.

References:

1. https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html
2. http://www.pgpool.net

Comment: Hi Sebastian! Thanks for quick response! :) I had a question like can we configure / reload it via psql!